# Trying to point a puppet variable with the content of others variables

Tags: linux, puppet, devops

I'm writing a puppet code and need to point to a variable with the information of others.... to make it clear here is the example:

These are the variables with the information:

```
Array $users_ap1_dev = ['userdev1,userdev2'],
Array $users_ap2_prd = ['userprd1,userprd2'],
```

but **ap1** and **ap2** values are store in a fact calles **main_app** and **dev** and **prd** values are store in a fact called **env**.

I want to retrieve the info and create the user based on the fact information, something like

```
$dmz_users.each | String $user |{
user { $user:
  ensure => 'present',
}
```

So, how can i put the content of `$users_ap1_dev` into dmz_users, replacing ap1 and dev with the one store in the fact?

something like?:

```
 Array $dmz_user = "${users_${main_app}_${env}}"
```

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: This question and the information is rather confusing, but from what I can interpret, it seems like this information you have would be better stored as data in Hiera instead of in your code and facts. That would solve your problem and clean up your Puppet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the function: getvar()
It allows you to create a variable and put his content into another...
How to use it:

```
$dmz_users = getvar("users_${main_app}_${env}")
```

So let's says `$main_app = web` and '$env = prod', it will take this two values and will make '$dmz_users = $users_web_prod`